# Count event if another event happened after it using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns `uid=user_id`, `pid=product_id`, `events` and `timestamp`. I have to count total events per product. There are two ways to count events and then sum both results.

> The event C will be counted directly per uid and pid.
>
> Then I also have to count event A, only in case when event B is
>   followed by event A.

```
UID    PID       EVENT       Timestamp
1      001        A          2007-11-09 T 11:20
1      001        B          2007-11-09 T 11:21
1      003        C          2007-11-09 T 11:45
2      009        A          2007-11-09 T 11:50
2      010        A          2007-11-09 T 11:51
3      011        A          2007-11-09 T 11:55
3      011        B          2007-11-09 T 11:56
4      004        A          2007-11-09 T 11:20
4      005        A          2007-11-09 T 11:20
3      006        C          2007-11-09 T 11:20
4      006        C          2007-11-09 T 11:20
```

The data shown above is manually created to best describe my scenario and it may not be perfectly fitting real world data.

Edit:- result should be like given below. Where I am trying to show number of events per product.

```
pid     #event
001      1
003      1
004      0
005      0
006      2
009      0
010      0
011      1
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccf421/4

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: Added expected result after edit.

Comment: @user2816085 I worked out a solution for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896054/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-set-of-points-in-pyspark-dataframe. Please reach out if you still need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select uid,
       count(*) filter (where event = 'C') as cnt_c,
       count(*) filter (where event = 'B' and prev_event = 'A') as cnt_ab
from (select t.*,
             lag(event) over (partition by uid order by timestamp) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
group by uid;
```

EDIT:

You say you want this "per product" and then to sum them.  I think that is something like:

```
select pid,
       count(*) filter (where event = 'C' or event = 'B' and prev_event = 'A') as cnt
from (select t.*,
             lag(event) over (partition by pid, uid order by timestamp) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
group by pid;
```

Comment: Thank you. result should also differentiate on the basis of product_id (pid). I will test by adding pid and will reply. Thanks

Comment: @user2816085 . . . The second query should do what you want.